# Can Windows 7 or Vista's Snipping Tool capture a screen 10 seconds later, and capture the mouse pointer as well?

Tags: windows, screenshot, screen-capture, snipping

I wonder if Windows 7 or Vista's Snipping Tool can capture a screen 10 seconds later, and capture the mouse pointer as well?

The thing is that sometimes we need to capture the thing that "pops up" when the mouse is over it, so in that case, Snippling tool won't seem to work (because the mouse pointer is activating the Snipping tool instead of pointing at the thing to get the "pop up" item).  In this case, the key PrtScn on the keyboard can capture the screen to the clipboard, except it won't capture the mouse pointer, which is sometimes wanted...

Is there a way to do that, and possibly say, "capture the screen 10 seconds later, when I am all ready?"  thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, not using snipping tool :(

In Windows 7, you may have some luck using Problem Steps Recorder, which is free and included.

Either click the Start Orb and type in search "Problem Steps" then click on "Record steps to reproduce a problem", or a lot easier - Go to run (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and type "PSR"

Click Record, and it should be able to take screen shots at everything on screen that you click on. It combines everything in to a MHT file within a ZIP file, however, you can open up the MHT file and save any of the pictures (that are saved at full resolution).

Comment: Great tip! Thanks. I never knew such a tool existed. I chanced upon this thread trying to find Snagit capture problem of the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 40):

As per Snipping Tool help file.

1. Open the snipping tool and Hit `<Esc>` key to get out of snipping mode.
2. Setup the screen.
3. Hit `<Ctrl>` + `<PrtScn>`
4. Perform the snip.

This way, you can still get the open menus or popups or whatever is needed. 
However, you still won't get the cursor arrow.

Comment: I think you left out the part where you open the print screened image.

Comment: Actually, if you have Snipping Tool open first, hitting <Ctrl> + <PrtScn> will go into snipping mode with the menus open. No need to open up an image file.

Comment: Great tip! Never knew this!

Comment: My hat is off to you, sir! Thank you for this tip!

Comment: There are still flimsy popups that even do not withstand the pressing of the <Ctrl> key, and will vanish if you try this shortcut. As is the case with eclipse Javadoc popups.

Comment: For the life of me I don't know why this response isn't checked. PSR is clumsy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

[ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX) seems to a top contender in the FOSS category. As opposed to trialware/shareware that seems to be most tools.

Answer (score 1):

[Gadwin printscreen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) can capture the mouse.

Otherwise, although it might be a hassle, you could use an image manipulation program to paste a mouse image where you want it..?

Answer (score 1):

[FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) can capture after a delay and include the mouse pointer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At my job, I'm stuck with the snipping tool -- not allowed to install anything else. I came up with a work-around using a special PPT file and the MS Office Picture Manager that allows me to insert mouse pointer, cursor and annotations (a la SnagIt). If anyone is interested, write to david.s.domingo (at) uscg (dot) mil.

Answer (score 0):

I need to take print screens from my Remote Desktop using Citrix Receiver, and inside this VPC the print screen key doesn't work.

I tried a lot of methods and nothing worked. But with delay now it works.

---

You can use **Pinta**

It's a free, open source program for drawing and image editing.

**Pinta** has an option to print screen with delay:

[printscreen with delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJiCz.png)

[printscreen with delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucKgT.png)

web site: https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/

---

You can use **Greenshot**

It's a free, light-weight screenshot software tool for Windows.

When you press print-screen greenshot maintains yours menus and pop-ups opened, differently from the Windows native print-screen.

And if you want a delay, it has an option in the preferences.
Menu Settings -> Capture

web site: http://getgreenshot.org/

---

**Wink**

**Wink** is a freeware.
Using **Wink** you can capture screenshots, add explanations boxes, buttons, titles etc and generate a highly effective tutorial for your users.

web site: http://www.debugmode.com/wink/

Comment: Add links to their websites please, and for future reference try to follow this for recommending software: https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/543035

Comment: Thanks very much El8tedN8te, I tried, I made a beautiful post, and I was forced to change everything, the problem is that I'm new on the site, and I don't have permissions to add links, prints, etc, unless you give me points.

Answer (score 0):

Even, if you want to take a snap of your pop-up. There one functionality in snipping tool (it's not related with delay thing). Here you can open snipping tool first (win+R, then write 'snippingtool' press Enter, then cancel/ be out from it) after that you can make/process ahead for your pop-up. Once appear that pop-up immediately press 'Ctrl+PrtSc' keys. It should open snipping criteria for selecting the area.